# how to SELECT two different column From one table and get some id's twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this :

```
        id   firstname  lastname    cilinic1    cilinic2  ...   insurance1   insurance2
         1   rose       golabi      bla bla     bla bla          firaga        atena

        *2   ...         ...          ...        ...             filoli*       filoli*

         3   ...         ...          ...        ...              tomis         atena
         .
         .
         .
```

When user tries to search for a specific insurance like (atena) , I make a query like this:

```
        SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE insurance1 LIKE ($userinput) ..
```

But this query will search just in **insurance1**

The problem is , some doctors have 2 different clinics , and in each clinic maybe accept the same insurance (Like the row number 2 from this table , which I emphesized with * ) .

So , I have to search in both **insurance1** ANd **insurance2** simultaneously , and if a doctor accepts same insurance in 2 clinic , **I want to show that doctor twice in the search result**

what should I do ?

(NOTE:  I have to select * , because there are 12 columns in my table and I have to show everything in the search result(firstname,lastname,age,gender,city,....))

**Is There a way to say this sentence to mysql :**

```
      if you selected from **insurance1** then (function...)
      if you selected from **insurance2** then (function...)
```

????

Comment: check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine two separate queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE insurance1 LIKE ($userinput) ..
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE insurance2 LIKE ($userinput) ..
```

Comment: THanks, that worked perfect , but , consider this : 
If $userinput is like insurance1 , show clinic1 and if $userinput is like insurance2 show clinic2
then what I have to do ?
(thanks)

Comment: @andy: It can't be *that* hard to work out, surely?  `SELECT cilinic1 AS clinic FROM doctors WHERE insurance1 LIKE ($userinput) .. UNION ALL SELECT cilinic2 AS clinic FROM doctors WHERE insurance2 LIKE ($userinput) ..`?

Comment: @andy: However, this is all rather indicative of a schema that could benefit from [normalisation](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/problem-of-repeated-columns.html).